# Immediately redirect output of a program to a different directory

Tags: linux, command-line, directory, io-redirection

Normally, I call a program from inside `$path_to_program`, which accepts an initialization file. Basically, how I run it is `./program file.in`. After the program starts, it creates some binary output files (let's call them `out1, out2, out3`).

However, I would like to immediately move `out1, out2, out3` to another directory `$path_another` so that output files are not written inside `$path_to_program`. Is it possible to do that?

I tried different standard approaches, like calling my program from inside `$path_another` with `$path_to_program/program file.in`, but the `file.in` is not found. I found different methods, but most of them redirect output to `.txt` or `.log` file. I apologize, if this a duplicate question, but I couldn't find a working answer.

Comment: The way the vast majority of shell programs work, you need to specify both the path to the program and the path to any input files relative to the *working directory*. For example, if your shell is currently in `/etc` you can call `/usr/bin/cat /etc/hosts` *or* `/usr/bin/cat ./hosts` for the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
cd "${path_another}"
${path_to_program}/program "${path_to_program}/file.in"
```

Like I0b0 said in the comment above, the program probably expects "file.in" to be relative to the current directory (here `${path_another}`).  If it's in the same directory as the program, then you need to specify a path to that file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work --- the program returns, that it couldn't find the `file.in`. Note that this is what the program returns (not bash). Does a command similar to `./program file.in EXPORT_OUTCOME_IMMEDIATELY_TO_THIS_DIRECTORY` exist in Linux? Or another simple command with a similar end result?

Comment: @taj It all depends on the implementation of the program.  Programs can generate output anywhere they have permission to do so.  Some might generate them in the current working directory.  Some might generate them at a fixed path.  Some might use an environment variable to control where they generate their output.  There is no universal answer.